# smarty multidimensional array how print value

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, smarty

I'm trying to modify module in Prestashop 1.6.1.5. I stucked in smarty on printing value with foreach loop.

I have in smarty array `$obchody`

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2
        [active] => 1
        [mesto] => Praha
        [vzdalenost] => 86
        [name] => Praha - rozvoz
        [address1] => Praha
        [address2] => 
        [postcode] => 10200
        [latitude] => 25.94896900
        [longitude] => -80.22643900
        [hours] => a:7:{i:0;s:0:"";i:1;s:0:"";i:2;s:0:"";i:3;s:0:"";i:4;s:0:"";i:5;s:0:"";i:6;s:0:"";}
        [phone] => 
        [fax] => 
        [note] => 
        [email] => 
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 3
        [active] => 1
        [mesto] => Aš
        [vzdalenost] => 133
        [name] => Aš - rozvoz
        [address1] => Aš
        [address2] => 
        [postcode] => 35201
        [latitude] => 25.94896900
        [longitude] => -80.22643900
        [hours] => a:7:{i:0;s:0:"";i:1;s:0:"";i:2;s:0:"";i:3;s:0:"";i:4;s:0:"";i:5;s:0:"";i:6;s:0:"";}
        [phone] => 
        [fax] => 
        [note] => 
        [email] => 
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [active] => 1
        [mesto] => Liberec
        [vzdalenost] => 192
        [name] => Liberec - rozvoz
        [address1] => Liberec
        [address2] => 
        [postcode] => 46001
        [latitude] => 25.94896900
        [longitude] => -80.22643900
        [hours] => a:7:{i:0;s:0:"";i:1;s:0:"";i:2;s:0:"";i:3;s:0:"";i:4;s:0:"";i:5;s:0:"";i:6;s:0:"";}
        [phone] => 
        [fax] => 
        [note] => 
        [email] => 
    )

)
```

and I'm trying to get `[name]` value in my template with

```
{foreach $obchody as $obchod}
{$obchod->name}
{/foreach}
```

But i always get only notice "Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in...". I tried `{$obchod[0]->name}` with same result. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Reginol_Blindhop have you tried to read the [documentation](https://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.variables.tpl) of Smarty?

Answer (score 0):

The syntax to print the [properties of associative arrays](https://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.variables.tpl#language.variables.assoc.arrays) is `{$array.key}`.

Accordingly, the Smarty code for your data structure should be:

```
{foreach $obchody as $obchod}
    {$obchod.name}
{/foreach}
```

Read how to handle the [assigned variables](https://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.variables.tpl) in the Smarty documentation.

Comment: Thx a lot. It's working. Problem was that i didn't know what i should search.